# should I have a voxel class, or have all the data processed in a chunk?

Tags: c#, voxel

I'm in the works of making a personal voxelized terrain system for Unity, which I may later translate to C++, because having portable code is convenient.  I also have plans to use Marching cubes, and I have made a decent result to appear in a singular chunk.  I also just recently put in a system where if the density of a vertex is 0, no voxel class is produced.

I know it's a frowned-upon idea to optimize early, but I was just curious on this subject.

Would it be better for performance to have all the data processed and stored in a single chunk, or continue using a voxel class like I am now?

Just to give an idea of what I have, here's some pseudo-code.

```
class voxel
{
    Vector3 Vertices[8]
    void Polygonize()
    // This filters a list of triangles and all that.
}

class chunk
{
    int GridSize
    Voxel vox[GridSize][GridSize][GridSize]
    float Density[GridSize + 1][GridSize + 1][GridSize + 1]

    void GenerateMatrix()
    {
        for every voxel in Density
        {
            if Density[x, y, z]  > 0
            {
                // Do all the things.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should compare performance of class against struct. If you still need more performance, you may try chunks in C++ or even with GPGPU libraries on C++(Arrayfire) or C# side such as https://github.com/tugrul512bit/Cekirdekler/wiki or OpenTK